# Cast a void pointer to a struct or memcpy to new struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am passing a `void *` as an argument to a function `foo(void* parm)` which calls function `bar(STmyStruct* parm)`
Should I cast the void pointer to `STmyStruct*` or create a new struct, memcpy what the `void*` points to and then pass a pointer to that struct?
I guess solution A is more efficient?

```
A:    foo(void* parm)
      {
       bar((STmyStruct*) parm)
      }

B:    foo(void* parm)
      {
       STmyStruct myStr;
       memcpy(&myStr, parm, sizeof(STmyStruct));
       bar(&myStr)
      }


bar(STmyStruct* mystr);
```

Comment: Stop doing all of these things, you're using C++

Comment: Why would you copy it? It is no safer, if what `parm` is pointing at isn't that struct, the second method won't fail any sooner. The only reason to do B is that if you modify what pointed at in `bar` you won't damage the original data.

Comment: Solution A should be fine, from what I've seen. You just need to be sure your `void*` really _is_ a `STmyStruct*`, since the compiler won't check that for you.

Comment: Please could you tell us why you're passing a void* to the function in the first place, as I'm sure it is not necessary!

Comment: I am reading raw data from a usb data transfer. And what I also should have mentioned is, `bar()` is actually an `ioctl()`, so it doesn't modify the data (Since it's an iocontrol that doesn't write to the parameter).

Answer (score 2):

- If you can avoid dealing in `void*` at all, do so. But you are probably bound by an existing API.
- If the `void*` actually points to a `STmyStruct*`, just cast.
- If the `void*` doesn't point to a `STmyStruct*` but something layout-compatible (so that cross-memcpy is legal), which should be a really rare case, then you have to go with option B due to aliasing rules, or risk confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the two solution do different things, the solution A you pass the parameter by reference, so if you inside function `bar` change something you will change what was passed to `foo`, it means:

```
STmyStruct test;
// your code that uses test
foo(test);
```

if function bar changes the mystr parameter, you will change test too.

But in the solution B, you copy the parameter `parm`, using memcpy, so if the function `bar` changes its parameter, you won't change `parm`. It means:

```
STmyStruct test;
// your code that uses test
foo(test);
```

Even if you change parameter `mystr` inside function `bar`, test won't change, because you copy its value to `myStr`.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your use case. Generally, both are fine, assuming that `parm` really points to an object of type `STMyStruct`.

If `bar` modifies `mystr` and you want the original `param` to be modified, you have to use option A.

If it modifies `mystr` and you do NOT want `param` to be modified, you need option B.

If bar does not modify `mystr`, then A would be more efficient, but B would not be a problem, either. (Except if B stored a pointer to `mystr` anywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you expect `bar` to modify the item you've got a pointer to, or whether you want it to work on a copy.